# Select two statements in one view

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have View called `VW_STOCKOPNAME`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW VW_STOCKOPNAME AS SELECT
A.M_STOCKCODE_KL_ID,
A.M_STOCKCODE_JB_ID,
A.M_STOCKCODE_NB_ID,
A.M_STOCKCODE_SB_ID,
B."NAME" AS S1_KL,
C."NAME" AS S2_JB,
D."NAME" AS S3_NB,
E."NAME" AS S4_SB,
A.M_ASSETCODE_GOLONGAN_ID,
A.M_ASSETCODE_BIDANG_ID,
A.M_ASSETCODE_KELOMPOK_ID,
A.M_ASSETCODE_SUBKELOMPOK_ID,
A.M_ASSETCODE_SUBSUBKEL_ID,
F."NAME" AS A1_GOLONGAN,
G."NAME" AS A2_BIDANG,
H."NAME" AS A3_KELOMPOK,
I."NAME" AS A4_SUBKELOMPOK,
J."NAME" AS A5_SUBSUBKEL,
A.M_PRODUCT_ID,
K."NAME" AS PRODUCT,
L."NAME" AS UOM,
A.QTYBOOK,
A.QTYCOUNT,
A.DIFFERENCE,
N.M_WAREHOUSE_ID,
O."NAME" AS WAREHOUSE

FROM M_INVENTORYLINE A

LEFT JOIN M_STOCKCODE_KL B ON B.M_STOCKCODE_KL_ID = A.M_STOCKCODE_KL_ID
LEFT JOIN M_STOCKCODE_JB C ON C.M_STOCKCODE_JB_ID = A.M_STOCKCODE_JB_ID
LEFT JOIN M_STOCKCODE_NB D ON D.M_STOCKCODE_NB_ID = A.M_STOCKCODE_NB_ID
LEFT JOIN M_STOCKCODE_SB E ON E.M_STOCKCODE_SB_ID = A.M_STOCKCODE_SB_ID

LEFT JOIN M_ASSETCODE_GOLONGAN F ON F.M_ASSETCODE_GOLONGAN_ID = A.M_ASSETCODE_GOLONGAN_ID
LEFT JOIN M_ASSETCODE_BIDANG G ON G.M_ASSETCODE_BIDANG_ID = A.M_ASSETCODE_BIDANG_ID
LEFT JOIN M_ASSETCODE_KELOMPOK H ON H.M_ASSETCODE_KELOMPOK_ID = A.M_ASSETCODE_KELOMPOK_ID
LEFT JOIN M_ASSETCODE_SUBKELOMPOK I ON I.M_ASSETCODE_SUBKELOMPOK_ID = A.M_ASSETCODE_SUBKELOMPOK_ID

LEFT JOIN M_ASSETCODE_SUBSUBKEL J ON J.M_ASSETCODE_SUBSUBKEL_ID = A.M_ASSETCODE_SUBSUBKEL_ID
LEFT JOIN M_PRODUCT K ON K.M_PRODUCT_ID = A.M_PRODUCT_ID
LEFT JOIN C_UOM L ON L.C_UOM_ID = A.C_UOM_ID
LEFT JOIN M_INVENTORY N ON N.M_INVENTORY_ID = A.M_INVENTORY_ID

LEFT JOIN M_WAREHOUSE O ON O.M_WAREHOUSE_ID = N.M_WAREHOUSE_ID
;
```

I want to add another column which has command as follows :

```
SELECT S1_KL ||'-'|| S2_JB ||'-'|| S3_NB ||'-'|| S4_SB AS ASSET_CODE
FROM VW_STOCKOPNAME
```

It shows group of codes from the columns in the view to make it easier to see.

How can I add it?

Comment: You can simply add `S1_KL ||'-'|| S2_JB ||'-'|| S3_NB ||'-'|| S4_SB AS ASSET_CODE` on your select statement that defines your view

Comment: You will have to recreate the view using CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW view_name .............

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW VW_STOCKOPNAME AS SELECT
A.M_STOCKCODE_KL_ID,
A.M_STOCKCODE_JB_ID,
A.M_STOCKCODE_NB_ID,
A.M_STOCKCODE_SB_ID,
B."NAME" AS S1_KL,
C."NAME" AS S2_JB,
D."NAME" AS S3_NB,
E."NAME" AS S4_SB,
A.M_ASSETCODE_GOLONGAN_ID,
A.M_ASSETCODE_BIDANG_ID,
A.M_ASSETCODE_KELOMPOK_ID,
A.M_ASSETCODE_SUBKELOMPOK_ID,
A.M_ASSETCODE_SUBSUBKEL_ID,
F."NAME" AS A1_GOLONGAN,
G."NAME" AS A2_BIDANG,
H."NAME" AS A3_KELOMPOK,
I."NAME" AS A4_SUBKELOMPOK,
J."NAME" AS A5_SUBSUBKEL,
A.M_PRODUCT_ID,
K."NAME" AS PRODUCT,
L."NAME" AS UOM,
A.QTYBOOK,
A.QTYCOUNT,
A.DIFFERENCE,
N.M_WAREHOUSE_ID,
O."NAME" AS WAREHOUSE,
B."NAME" ||'-'|| C."NAME" ||'-'|| D."NAME" ||'-'|| E."NAME" AS ASSET_CODE

FROM M_INVENTORYLINE A

LEFT JOIN M_STOCKCODE_KL B ON B.M_STOCKCODE_KL_ID = A.M_STOCKCODE_KL_ID
LEFT JOIN M_STOCKCODE_JB C ON C.M_STOCKCODE_JB_ID = A.M_STOCKCODE_JB_ID
LEFT JOIN M_STOCKCODE_NB D ON D.M_STOCKCODE_NB_ID = A.M_STOCKCODE_NB_ID
LEFT JOIN M_STOCKCODE_SB E ON E.M_STOCKCODE_SB_ID = A.M_STOCKCODE_SB_ID

LEFT JOIN M_ASSETCODE_GOLONGAN F ON F.M_ASSETCODE_GOLONGAN_ID = A.M_ASSETCODE_GOLONGAN_ID
LEFT JOIN M_ASSETCODE_BIDANG G ON G.M_ASSETCODE_BIDANG_ID = A.M_ASSETCODE_BIDANG_ID
LEFT JOIN M_ASSETCODE_KELOMPOK H ON H.M_ASSETCODE_KELOMPOK_ID = A.M_ASSETCODE_KELOMPOK_ID
LEFT JOIN M_ASSETCODE_SUBKELOMPOK I ON I.M_ASSETCODE_SUBKELOMPOK_ID = A.M_ASSETCODE_SUBKELOMPOK_ID

LEFT JOIN M_ASSETCODE_SUBSUBKEL J ON J.M_ASSETCODE_SUBSUBKEL_ID = A.M_ASSETCODE_SUBSUBKEL_ID
LEFT JOIN M_PRODUCT K ON K.M_PRODUCT_ID = A.M_PRODUCT_ID
LEFT JOIN C_UOM L ON L.C_UOM_ID = A.C_UOM_ID
LEFT JOIN M_INVENTORY N ON N.M_INVENTORY_ID = A.M_INVENTORY_ID

LEFT JOIN M_WAREHOUSE O ON O.M_WAREHOUSE_ID = N.M_WAREHOUSE_ID
;
```